# Can I generate markdown documentation based on typescript cloud functions?

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-functions, documentation

I have a couple of cloud functions written in TypeScript located in subdirectory of my monorepo. I'd like to automatically generate README.md file including list of all the functions along with the basic description pulled from the comments in the .ts files.

For instance I may have a function as follows:

```
/* 
    This function is...
*/
export const doSomethingImportant = functions
    .runWith({ minInstances: parseInt(process.env.MIN_INSTANCES ?? "0", 0), maxInstances: 10, memory: "256MB" })
    .region("us-central1", "europe-west1")
    .https
    .onRequest(async (request, response) => {
```

I'd like the output to include all the defined functions and include information such as:

- this is a https function with a given name and region, for callable functions similar info
- the comment above the function
- potentially what kind of responses it can end up with

Is there any tool that does something at least similar to that?

I found [typedoc](https://typedoc.org/) but this is more like API docs for a library whereas I'd like to have something like an overview of all the functions.